# GXT 3.1 : Neptune Theme not applied

Tags: gwt, gxt

i'm currently using GXT 3.1.1 and i'm trying to change the graphic theme to use the Neptune theme display.
To do so, i added the following lines in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gxt-theme-neptune</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I also added the following code in my .gwt.xml file

```
<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.theme.neptune.Theme' />
```

The jars are added to my lib folder but when i deploy my war, the only display change I notice is the font change (which is now bold and bigger) in my Standard theme (btw, yes i did comment the row about the standard theme in my .gwt.xml file)

Has anyone experienced the same phenomenon?
Thx

**Edit**

I'm using java 1.6. Does this version enable the use of the Neptune theme?

Comment: Are you sure your browser is not showing you a cached version of your application (using the old theme)? Have you tried a "hard" refresh (Ctrl+F5) or clearing the cache?

Comment: Yep. Just tried the hard refresh. Doesn't change a thing. Thanks anyway. Any other idea?

Comment: Make sure the inherits tag for neptune should be below the inherits tag for GXT. I.e. 

    <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT' />
    <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.theme.neptune.Theme' />

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in your .gwt.xml

```
<inherits name="com.sencha.gxt.themebuilder.base.ThemeBase" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't affect the display. Am I supposed to add this row instead of the neptune theme row, or in addition to it?

Comment: In addition. And add sencha ThemeBuilder to maven dependencies list. By the way, what version of GWT do you use?

Comment: I added the dependecy but the display remains as it was